# How to speed up the construction of a matrix without using a double for loop

Tags: python, performance, numpy, for-loop, matrix

I want to the accelerate following double `for` loop:

```
n = 10000
A = np.zeros((n, n))
twopi = 2.0 * np.pi
for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(0, n):
        A[i,j] = twopi * i*j/n
```

How could I do it? My idea: compute a vector `v` containing all the elements from `0` to `n-1`:

```
v = np.arange(n)
```

then construct two matrices `I` and `J`, one having all rows equal to `v` and the other one having all columns equal to `v`. If I'm not mistaken, then I could substitute the double `for` loop with

```
A = twopi * I*J/n
```

Is this correct? How do I build `I` and `J`? Are there better ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## An answer

You can indeed use `numpy`'s broadcasting ability.

```
import numpy as np
n = 10000
twopi = 2.0 * np.pi / n
A = np.arange(n) * np.arange(n).reshape(-1, 1) * twopi
```

The reshape of the second `np.arange()` drives the product to broadcast.

It's very similar to calling `np.outer()` as [Dr.V did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67905827/10409093), even from a time performance perspective.

## A benchmark

Config:

```
import numpy as np
n = 10000
twopi = 2 * np.pi / n
```

Times:

```
# List comprehension
A = np.array([   
    [twopi*i*j for j in range(n)] 
for i in range(n)])
# timeit > 10.2 s ± 129 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# Outer
i = np.arange(n)
A = twopi * np.outer(i, i)
# timeit > 234 ms ± 6.87 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# Product
A = np.arange(n) * np.arange(n).reshape(-1, 1) * twopi
# timeit > 208 ms ± 41.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

As said, the outer and product methods are very similar.
But the list comprehension is not because it defeats the purpose of numpy which is to vectorize the array computations with distributed sub-tasks (and, very often, low-level optimizations).

Comment: Thanks! Quick question: what's the meaning of `reshape(-1, 1)`?

Comment: In this specific case, it produces from a 1D array of shape `10000`, a 2D array of shape `(1, 10000)`. It's like making a column vector from a row vector. The `-1` argument means ***as much as needed to fit all the values***, which is 10000 here. In other cases, as an exemple you could reshape an array of shape `8` into an array of shape `(2, 2, 2)` by doing `an_array.reshape(2, 2, 2)`.

Comment: last question: how did you generate the `timeit` numbers? Do you have a link which shows how to do it?

Comment: Sure. Here is the doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html. I personally use it in notebooks (Jupyter) with the magic command `%%timeit` at the first line of any cell I want to measure the execution time.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
from numpy import outer, pi, arange

n = 10
i = arange(n)
A = 2 * pi / n * outer(i, i)
```

The `outer` product does what you ask for.

**Edit:**
A simple way to test performance is the following:

```
from time import time

n = 10000
t = time()
for _ in range(10):
    i = arange(n)
    A = 2 * pi / n * outer(i, i)

t = time() - t
print("Time used [s]", t)
```

For me, it uses 5 seconds for these 10 repetitions, and there is no significant difference between `range` and `arange`.

Comment: Looks cool! It would be interesting to see abenchmark some of the best solutions published so far. If you don't feel like modifying your answer to include one, could you point me to an existing answer which helps me do that?

Comment: I don't have time now, sorry ... but one thing to consider: Numpy's `arange` actually creates that array in memory, while the built-in `range` doesn't. I just don't know at this point whether the `outer` function then anyway makes an `array` out of the arguments.
Hence: I recommend to perform the tests both with `range` and `arange`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehensions:

```
A = np.array([   
        [twopi*i*j/n for j in range(n)] 
    for i in range(n)])
```

The default is for `range` to start at zero, so `range(0,n)` rather than `range(n)`is redundant.

Comment: Impressive! Will need to benchmark this. If @Dr.V doesn't want to include some benchmarking, maybe you would?  On the `arange` default thing: you're right, I wrote the post in a hurry but I could have simplified that call.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [118]: matrix = np.array([np.arange(n) for _ in range(n)])

In [119]: matrix
Out[119]:
array([[   0,    1,    2, ..., 9997, 9998, 9999],
       [   0,    1,    2, ..., 9997, 9998, 9999],
       [   0,    1,    2, ..., 9997, 9998, 9999],
       ...,
       [   0,    1,    2, ..., 9997, 9998, 9999],
       [   0,    1,    2, ..., 9997, 9998, 9999],
       [   0,    1,    2, ..., 9997, 9998, 9999]])

In [120]: matrix [0,1]
Out[120]: 1

In [121]: for j in range(n): matrix[:,j] *= j

In [122]: matrix
Out[122]:
array([[       0,        1,        4, ..., 99940009, 99960004, 99980001],
       [       0,        1,        4, ..., 99940009, 99960004, 99980001],
       [       0,        1,        4, ..., 99940009, 99960004, 99980001],
       ...,
       [       0,        1,        4, ..., 99940009, 99960004, 99980001],
       [       0,        1,        4, ..., 99940009, 99960004, 99980001],
       [       0,        1,        4, ..., 99940009, 99960004, 99980001]])

In [123]: matrix = matrix/n

In [124]: matrix = matrix * np.pi*2

In [125]: matrix
Out[125]:
array([[0.00000000e+00, 6.28318531e-04, 2.51327412e-03, ...,
        6.27941596e+04, 6.28067228e+04, 6.28192873e+04],
       [0.00000000e+00, 6.28318531e-04, 2.51327412e-03, ...,
        6.27941596e+04, 6.28067228e+04, 6.28192873e+04],
       [0.00000000e+00, 6.28318531e-04, 2.51327412e-03, ...,
        6.27941596e+04, 6.28067228e+04, 6.28192873e+04],
       ...,
       [0.00000000e+00, 6.28318531e-04, 2.51327412e-03, ...,
        6.27941596e+04, 6.28067228e+04, 6.28192873e+04],
       [0.00000000e+00, 6.28318531e-04, 2.51327412e-03, ...,
        6.27941596e+04, 6.28067228e+04, 6.28192873e+04],
       [0.00000000e+00, 6.28318531e-04, 2.51327412e-03, ...,
        6.27941596e+04, 6.28067228e+04, 6.28192873e+04]])
```

Same thing as a script:

```
matrix = np.array([np.arange(n) for _ in range(n)])
for j in range(n): matrix[:,j] *= j
matrix = matrix/n
matrix = matrix * np.pi*2
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to read your code like this. Could you format it as a script, rather than a succession of REPL commands?